# cross correlation javascript, sliding dot-product & sum of squared differences as the similarity metric

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, cross-correlation

I need to Cross- correlate a pattern in the provided signal with a sliding dot-product and also with the sum of squared differences as the similarity metric.
I'm working in a javascript nodejs environment and have found this formula, Corr(x,y) => fft(x) * fft(y)*
I have also found Fast Fourier Transform functions already written in JS but don't really know how to multiply the returns arrays to derive where the cross correlation in maximized.
I also don't know how to add the sliding dot-product and sum of squared differences similarity metric into the equation.